# Checking If a String Contains a Word and Then Checking If It Starts With said Word and If It Doesnt?

Tags: c#, .net

Having another tough one here guys, basically I would like to check if a string contains the word "Foo" and if it does contain it, does it start with it? If it does start with Foo, it should be the only Foo that starts with a capital, all others should be small letters.

If the above criteria is met, it should return true.

If the string contains Foo but doesn't start with Foo, it should immediately return false since you cant have a capital Foo in the middle of the string.

In the event that said string contains foo, but doesn't start with Foo, all instances of foo should be lowercase. If this criteria is met, return true.

I should mention i am looking for C# code, I tried and have not yet succeeded, but since I have only been programming for 2 weeks, I don't think this will be trouble for some of you season pro's.

---

This is what I have tried as requested, I thinks its faaar off but at least I tried.

```
            if (Title.Contains("Foo") == true && Regex.IsMatch(Title, "^Foo") == true)
        {
            CheckAnd = true;
        }
        else if (Title.Contains("Foo") == true && Regex.IsMatch(Title, "^Foo") == false)
        {
            CheckAnd = false;
        }
        else if (Regex.IsMatch(Title, "^foo"))
        {
            CheckAnd = false;
        }
        else
        {
            CheckAnd = true;
        }
```

---

Ok guys, nearly there, this is what I got from all your answers:

```
if (Title.IndexOf("Foo") == 0 && Title.LastIndexOf("Foo") == 0)
        {
            CheckAnd = true;
        }
        else if (Title.LastIndexOf("Foo") > 0)
        {
            CheckAnd = false;
        }
        else if(Title.Contains("foo") && Title.StartsWith("Foo") == false && PUT CHECK HERE)
```

The last thing I need to check that all occurrences of foo are lowercase in the last else if statement ?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Seems like you want us to solve a school problem

Comment: hahahah not quite, im validating file names. I just program as a hobby, ive just started and im really enjoying it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I undestood it correctly this should do it !

```
    if (testString.IndexOf("Foo") == 0 && testString.LastIndexOf("Foo") == 0)
        // "Foo foo foo"
        return true;
    else if (testString.IndexOf("Foo") == 0 && testString.LastIndexOf("Foo") > 0)
        // "Foo foo Foo"
        return false;
    else if (testString.Contains("foo")  && testString.IndexOf("Foo") > 0)
        // "foo Foo foo" or "foo foo Foo"
        return false; 
    else if (testString.Contains("foo") && !testString.Contains("Foo"))
        // "foo foo foo"
        return true;
```

Comment: This doesn't account for the string containing lower case "foo"

Comment: at first glance yours would appear to work, but the last check isn't exactly right, im working to tweak I though, when I get it, ill mark yours as the answer

Comment: So why doesn't the last check work? What is the rule to apply?

Comment: String contains foo, but doesn't start with Foo, all instances of foo should be lowercase. --> Only lowercase foo in the string right?

Comment: yeah ? am I missing something? :), I marked it as the answer in the mean time though, but how would I do the last check ?

Comment: Well else if (testString.Contains("foo") && !testString.Contains("Foo")) validates exactly that. Only "foo" in the string no "Foo" existant.

Comment: oh snap, you know what I never saw the exclamation mark. Thank you SO SO much!

Comment: This and other answers here overlook one glaring problem:  OP wants to see if a string contains a *word*, not just a partial string.  The example in this answer would break if the test string contained the word "fool", "football", etc since they all contain "foo" but aren't actually the word "foo".

Answer (score 17):

## Don't want to read my book? Here's the answer:

*As a bonus, this is the fastest performing solution.*

```
public void CheckValidFoo(String Title) {     
    return (Title.LastIndexOf("Foo") <= 0);
}
```

## Read on for a lessons in coding logic (humor this old man)

This question may be old, but **for the sake of those finding this question *later* who are *curious* about how to logically distill word problems**, here's my massively overdone analysis for this extremely simple homework assignment:

I ran a set of tests to see what options were the fastest - this often helps me see flaws in my logic. I am also going to explain my thought process, since, IMHO, understanding how to distill a problem to it's core logic is a good thing to know for real world use.

After all, that's what Business Requirements Docs are... word problems that need to be distilled into functional specs (e.g. architectural design).

## Step 1

*Eliminate Extraneous Information*
Based on the requirements given, lower case foo may or may not matter:  There is no explicit statement that a string not containing foo and not containing Foo should return false;  There is also no explicit statement that says a string not containing Foo and not containing foo should return true.

In a perfect world, you would go back for clarification on the requirements, but in some cases, there isn't time.  Assuming there is a deadline, I would move forward with the assumption that all we care about is Foo being uppercase only when in the first position in the sentence, lower case at all other times, so we will ignore foo altogether, and if the "client" complains, point out the missing clarity and explain why you made a judgement call (to keep the project on time, and on budget, if applicable).

## Step 2

*Break down the logic into OR/AND pieces:*
Breaking Foo into components lets us look at individual pieces, which can be easier than looking at the whole.  So, if we break the string into "stuff before Foo" (even if that is "nothing") and "stuff after Foo" OR if Foo isn't there to break up the string, we only have one piece to look at.  (Our brains do this all the time - it's called pattern recognition).

IF **The string cannot be split because Foo is not found**
    OR
      **splitting on Foo gives us no more than two pieces: nothing before, and everything after**
       *AND* (implied by the previous check only finding an empty "before" and only one "section" in the "after")
      **Foo is not found anywhere else in the string**

Sound good? Well, it's 100% accurate, but we can cut some cruft and distill it further - keep in mind computers don't think like humans, so our mental processing is inefficient for them.

Because Foo not being found at all is considered valid, and Foo at the beginning is valid, but Foo anywhere else later in the string is invalid, we can say:

IF **Foo is not found**
    OR
      **Foo is not found anywhere in the string past the first position**

Seems tight, right?  Don't stop now.  We can do better.

If Foo is found at the beginning, we're fine with it, right?  So "Foo is not Found" OR "Foo is found at the beginning AND Foo is not found anywhere else" can be looked at from a more pure logic (boolean, true/false, black and white) perspective:

- LET FNA = "Foo is not found anywhere"
- LET FN1 = "Foo is not found in position 1"
- LET FN2 = "Foo is not found after position 1"
- LET FF1 = "Foo is found in position 1"
- LET FF2 = "Foo is found after position 1"

So now define as invalid only those cases which are guaranteed invalid, and mark the rest as valid.  We'll use boolean math to determine all use cases.

- LET FNA = valid
- LET FN1 = valid
- LET FN2 = valid
- LET FF1 = valid
- LET FF2 = invalid

Now that we've labeled only the cases that absolutely force a return of false, we can do the math to see the only cases where we get an invalid/false value.

FNA = FN1 and FN2 (so if FNA & X = true, then F1 & X must be true, and F2 & X must also be true);

FNA and/or FF1 = true, so we know that all combinations of and/or of these 4 variables = true;  This leaves only one variable left to combine, and we can see really quickly that FF2 and anything will always be false.

So translated back into human logic... see how much simpler this task is?

**ONLY FALSE IF** ***Foo is found after position 1***

Or, to flip the boolean (since the requirements say to return true for valid cases):

IF **Foo is NOT found after position 1, string is valid.**

Or, to put it more like a computer's thinking:

IF **scanning from the *end* of the string until the 2nd to the last character does not find Foo, string is valid**

There, now we can't distill it any further down.  So let's code these different bits of logic and see how they perform in real code:

```
using System;

public static class Test
{
public static bool CheckFooTestA(String SearchMe, String[] FindMe)
{
    //split the string like the human eye does and check the count of Foos 
    //and the position of the Foo or Foos to determine our logic:
    string[] v = SearchMe.Split(FindMe, StringSplitOptions.None);
    
         //Foo not found, OR foo found once and was at the beginning of the string
    return (v.Length == 0 || v.Length == 1 && v[0] == String.Empty);
}
public static bool CheckFooTestB(String SearchMe, String[] FindMe)
{
    //scan the way computers or non-speed readers do, and look for the first instance of Foo
    int i = SearchMe.IndexOf(FindMe[0]);

    //Foo not found OR 
    //    foo found at the start of the string 
    //    AND the last Foo found is also at the start of the string
    return (i == -1 || i == 0 && SearchMe.LastIndexOf(FindMe[0]) == 0 );
}
public static bool CheckFooTestC(String SearchMe, String[] FindMe)
{
    //Use the logic we distilled from the word problem to make this single check:
    return (SearchMe.LastIndexOf(FindMe[0]) <= 0);
}
public static void Main()
{
    String[] x = new String[]{
        "Foo foo Foo bar",
        "Foo foo foo bar",
        "foo foo Foo bar",
        "foo foo foo bar",
        "asfda asdfa asf" };
        
    var s = new []{"Foo"};
    var i = 0;
    bool f=false;
    long End = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    long Start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    for (; i < 1000; i++) {
        f = CheckFooTestA(x[i%5],s);
    }
    End = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    Console.WriteLine((End - Start).ToString() + " ticks (Test A)");

    i = 0;
    f = false;
    End = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    Start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    for (; i < 1000; i++) {
        f = CheckFooTestB(x[i%5],s);
    }
    End = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    Console.WriteLine((End - Start).ToString() + " ticks (Test B)");
    
    i = 0;
    f = false;
    End = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    Start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    for (; i < 1000; i++) {
        f = CheckFooTestC(x[i%5],s);
    }
    End = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    Console.WriteLine((End - Start).ToString() + " ticks (Test C)");
}
}
Test.Main();
```

### Output:

```
260510 ticks (Test A)
117150 ticks (Test B)
76160 ticks (Test C)
```

## Results and Conclusions

Test A (human logic of visually splitting on/counting the words found), compared to test B (scanning using indexes with the distilled logic), Test A runs over 220% longer!

Test C is the best performer - only one scan of the string needed.  Coming in at less than 30% the processing time required (Test A takes over 340%! of the amount of time Test C requires to complete the same work).

So hopefully some student somewhere has read this and the lightbulb goes on.  You can always come up with ways to make stuff that "works", but understanding boolean logic and how to distill a concept down to it's core can make a significant impact on the quality of your work.

Answer (score 2):

this will return `true` (because it contains the word Foo), and then `false` (because Foo isnt at the start of the sentence).

```
        string word = "I am a string i contain Foo, aint that nice?";
        bool conts = word.Contains("Foo");
        int pos = word.IndexOf("Foo");                 
        if (conts)
        {
            if (pos != 0)
            {
                // do something
            }

        }
```

Comment: The string "Fun at the park is Foo, coo." would validate as well, which would be incorrect. [String.ComareOrdinal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/es986b3k.aspx) could be used to validate the start of the string anyway using the (string, int string, int, int) overload.

Comment: @Joshua very true. didnt think of that :)

Comment: Oo, interesting edit. You could combine the entire portion with one call to `LastIndexOf`. If it's -1 then the string isn't found, if it's 0 then it is the correct case and starts the string, and if it's greater than 0, it fails the final part: "it should be the only Foo that starts with a capital".

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to String.IndexOf Method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx

The search is case sensitive, so just look for the capitalized word (Ex: "Foo"). If IndexOf returns 0, then the word is at the first position.

Edit: This is how I would do it (after seeing your code)

```
//changed to check for lowercase foo
if ((Title.StartsWith("Foo") && Title.LastIndexOf("Foo") == 0) 
|| (Title.Contains("foo") && !Title.StartsWith("foo")))
{
    CheckAnd = true;
}
else
    CheckAnd = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly this method should work.

```
    public bool ContainsFoo(string s)
    {
        bool result = true;

        if (s.IndexOf("Foo") > 0)
        {
            result = false;
        }
        else if (s.LastIndexOf("Foo") > 0)
        {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Let me know if I misunderstood something.

Comment: I think the else part is redundant. If the first occurrence index is > 0, then the last occurrence is also > 0

Comment: @ForteL. I'm using the else to check if the string contains another "Foo" in which case it should return false.

Comment: yes, but notice that you method will return true even if the string doesn't contain "Foo" at all

Comment: @ForteL. In case the string does not contain Foo at all I will indeed check both if and else. It returns true if it does not contain "Foo" because OP said it should. "_In the event that said string contains foo, but doesn't start with Foo, all instances of foo should be lowercase._" - I'm assuming it doesn't matter if it contains "foo" or not.

Comment: I understand that it does matter if it contains "foo". If it doesn't then your code is fine.